# Z3: set starting values

Tags: z3

Can I ask Z3 to search from certain starting values to satisfy the constraints ?

Say, If I have two `RealExprs` `x` and `y`, and I have `x==y` as the constraint.
Can I ask Z3 to search from `x=-9999, y=-9997` such that Z3 might return to me a model with `x=-9998 and y=-9998` and say "SAT" ?

Comment: It seems you need "soft constraints", that is, `x >= -9999` and `y >= -9997` are constraints that you want to satisfy if possible. Is that right?

Comment: But that would constrain x and y with certain lower bounds. It is ok if I get x==y==-10000 as the result. I just want x and y to have certain starting values, the only constraint I have is x==y. Is it possible by z3?

Comment: Are you thinking of some kind of iterative process that, given starting values, iterates through the neighbourhood of those - and iteratively widens it - in order to find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, could be like that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you are kind of looking for a solution to a maximisation/minimisation problem, namely, of the following function

```
f(x, y) = |x + 9999| + |y + 9997|
```

together with the constraint `x = y`. As stated in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934545/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-variable), Z3 currently doesn't support this directly. However, as also stated, you can try to solve such problems by querying Z3 inside a Python loop that adds previously found solutions as new constraints of the next query.