# Getting the smaller model for a SMT formula

Tags: z3, smt

Let say that I have some formulas that can be sat but I want to get the smaller (or larger) possible value so sat that formula.

Is there a way to tell the SMT solver to give that kind of small solution?

Example:

a+1>10

In that example I want the SMT solver to give me the solution 10 instead of 100.

Cheers

NOTE: I have just seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934545/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-variable) answered by one of the z3 authors saying, three years ago, that they were implementing that functionality in z3. Do you know if it is already implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `maximize` and `minimize` [More info](http://rise4fun.com/z3opt/tutorialcontent/guide)

```
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (> (+ x 1) 10))
(minimize x)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: This works as of Z3 version 4.4.1.  It's not present in Z3 version 4.3.3, so it was added somewhere between those versions.