# z3py: Lower and upper bounds on variables?

Tags: z3, z3py

Preamble: I'm playing with z3py and trying to implement some decompositions of global constraints, e.g. `nvalue(n, x)` which ensures that there are exact `n` number of distinct values in the vector/array `x`. Constraint programming systems tend to have the possibility to extract lower and upper bounds of a decision variable - and I happen to be very fond of these global constraints.

My question is now if it is possible to get the lower and upper bounds of an variable, defined either as `Int`, `IntVector`, or `Array("x", IntSort(), IntSort())`?

(I've done some decomposition of global constraints already - see http://hakank.org/z3/ - but whenever the decomposition requires upper/lower bounds, I have to add these limits in the method call.)

Here is an example. Note that it use some my convenience methods defined in http://hakank.org/z3/z3_utils_hakank.py which simplifies the port from my constraint programming models; sorry if this is confusing.

The point is that the two values `min_value` and `max_value` has to be explicit added to the method `nvalue`.

```py
from z3_utils_hakank import *

# 
# ensure that there are exactly m distinct values in x
#
def nvalue(sol, m, x, min_val,max_val):
   n = len(x)
   sol.add(m == Sum([ If(Sum([ If(x[j] == i,1,0) for j in range(n)]) > 0,1,0) for i in range(min_val, max_val+1)]))

sol = Solver()

n = 5
min_val = 1 # <-- 
max_val = n # <-- 

# variables

m = makeIntVar(sol,"m",0,n)  # number of distinct values
x = makeIntVector(sol,"x",n, 1,n)

# constraints
nvalue(sol,m,x,min_val, max_val)

# solutions
num_solutions = 0
while sol.check() == sat:
  num_solutions += 1
  mod = sol.model()
  print "m:", mod.eval(m)
  print "x:", [mod.eval(x[i]) for i in range(n)]
  print
  getDifferentSolution(sol,mod,x)

print "num_solutions:", num_solutions
```

If would be great it the method definition of `nvalue` could be written something like this instead:

```py
def nvalue(sol, m, x):
   n = len(x)
   min_val = sol.min_val(x)
   max_val = sol.max_val(x)
   sol.add(m == Sum([ If(Sum([ If(x[j] == i,1,0) for j in range(n)]) > 0,1,0) for i in range(min_val, max_val+1)]))
```

i.e. using some z3py function such as `sol.min_value(x)` and `sol.max_val(x)`.

Comment: This is an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934545/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-variable/11947105#11947105), but I think it still outlines the *state of the art*, except for the fact that now it's possible to use `(minimize x)` and `(maximize x)` to obtain the lower/upper bounds of `x` on the formula. Since I don't know `z3`'s API in detail, I let someone else write an official answer to your question, as I may not be knowledgeable enough on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PatrickTrentin What I understand of these discussions about (minimize x) and (maximize x), is that they are for stating the upper/lower values of the optimizing variable of the model. PyZ3 now supports Optimize() which supports minimize(z) and maximize(z) which is nice, but not what I'm after.

What I am after is a method that give me the bounds as integer value - as a "plain Python integer" - for an arbitrary variable, not just for the optimization variable.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. The suggestion was more along the line of solving a separate **boxed** multi-objective optimization problem first, on all variables for which one needs to know upper/lower bounds, and then use those values in the problem one wants to solve. Not very efficient.

Comment: Ah, OK. No, I don't want to add another solving step because of this. Since I actually know all the bounds when writing the model, it's better to add these bounds as arguments to the methods.