# How can I solve minimizing constraint in Z3?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Could any one can tell me how I can implement minimizing integer problem like the below one by Z3py? How can I define for all statement? Here all variables are int sort.

[image: minimizing, for all statment]

Is there any dedicated solver within Z3 is available to solve such kind of problem? If there any, then how can I set configuration for that solver?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here are some relevant/similar questions and answers:

- [Minimum and maximum value of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934545/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-variable/11947105#11947105)
- [Determine upper/lower bound for variables in an arbitrary propositional formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995082/determine-upper-lower-bound-for-variables-in-an-arbitrary-propositional-formula)
- [How to optimize a piece of code in Z3? (PI_NON_NESTED_ARITH_WEIGHT related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513809/how-to-optimize-a-piece-of-code-in-z3-pi-non-nested-arith-weight-related)
- [Does Z3 have support for optimization problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211490/does-z3-have-support-for-optimization-problems)