# What is the best package to solve Binary Quadratic Optimization?

Tags: r

I have to solve Binary Quadratic Optimization problem i.e the objective function is quadratic, constraints are linear and variable are binary. I checked the "quadprog" package but it does not seem to be right choice for the problem.

Can any one suggest what would be the best package to solve the Binary Quadratic opt?

Comment: The CRAN optimization taskview lists your options. http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: Yes I have seen that. RCPLEX seems to be the right package but its not free. Free binary opt packages are only capable of opt linear objective function. Non linear opt package do not seem to have provision for binary variables. Any smart answers are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Microsoft Z3](http://z3.codeplex.com/) (cf [Stack Overflow question 8506142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506142/is-it-possible-to-find-optimal-solution-for-a-boolean-formula-by-smt-solvers)).